# Ceva's theorem on two triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> If two triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ are such that the perpendiculars from $A,B,C$ to $EF,FD,DE$ are concurrent, prove that the perpendiculars from $D,E,F$ to $BC,CA,AB$ are concurrent.

I tried to apply Ceva's theorem, but since the endpoints of the cevians are in separate triangles, I got nowhere.

Comment: If you want separate answers, you should post separate questions. (They're free!)

Comment: I reached the question limit

Comment: If you want, you can include both answers in the same post.

Comment: There are reasons for the question limit. (For one thing: We aren't here to do all of your homework for you.) Combining questions isn't the appropriate way to deal with that limit. If nothing else, you should note that answering multiple questions in the same answer denies the answerer the reputation points that would be available for having separate answers accepted on separate questions. Granted, reputation points are meaningless in the grand scheme of things, but they're how you say "Thank you" for the help you receive here. You should strive to *maximize* your gratitude.

Comment: This question was closed just as I was composing a straightforward, two-step proof using [Carnot's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Carnot.shtml). If the question re-opens, please ping me so that I can post my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like the "shaky" proofs given in the link of the first answer. So I am going to suggest another meticulous, careful proof, using only basic methods put together. Plus it shows you a lot of techniques, so it is good for educational purposes (personal opinion).

Let the three concurrent lines through the points $A, B, C$ and perpendicular to the lines  $EF, \,  FD, \, DE$ respectively intersect in the common point of intersection called $O_{ABC}$. Next, construct the three lines through the point $O_{ABC}$ and perpendicular to the edges $AB, \, BC, \, CA$ respectively and let $Q_{AB}, \, Q_{BC}, \, Q_{CA}$ be their corresponding intersection points, i.e. $Q_{AB}, \, Q_{BC}, \, Q_{CA}$ are the orthogonal projections of the point $O_{ABC}$ onto the edges $AB, \, BC, \, CA$ respectively. Furthermore, draw the tree lines $\sigma_A, \, \sigma_B,\, \sigma_C$ through the points $A, \, B, \, C$ perpendicular to the lines $AO_{ABC}, \, BO_{ABC}, \, CO_{ABC}$ respectively and let the three points $A_1, \, B_1, \, C_1$ be the following intersection points: 
$$A_1 = \sigma_B \cap \sigma_C, \,\, B_1 = \sigma_C \cap \sigma_A, \,\, C_1 = \sigma_A \cap \sigma_B$$  Consequently, we have constructed the triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ whose edges are parallel to the edges of the triangle $DEF$.

First I am going to prove the statement for the special case of triangles $ABC$ and $A_1B_1C_1$. From there, I am going to derive the general case for $ABC$ and $DEF$.

let $H_{A}, \, H_{B}, \, H_{C}$ be the orthocenters of the triangles $A_1BC, \, AB_1C, \, ABC_1$ respectively and let $P_{BC}, \, P_{CA}, \, P_{AB}$ be the intersection points of the altitudes $A_1H_{A}, \, B_1H_{B}, \, C_1H_{C}$
with the edges $BC, \, CA, \, AB$ respectively. Observe, by construction the lines $A_1H_A, \, \, B_1H_{B}, \, C_1H_{C}$ are perpendicular to the edges $BC, \, CA, \, AB$ respectively and our goal is to show that  $A_1H_A, \, \, B_1H_{B}, \, C_1H_{C}$  are concurrent.

Since both $CH_A$ (altitude) and $BO_{ABC}$ are orthogonal to $C_1A_1$ they are parallel to each other. Analogously, both $BH_A$ (altitude) and $CO_{ABC}$ are orthogonal to $A_1B_1$ they are parallel to each other. Consequently, the quad $CH_ABO_{ABC}$ is a parallelogram, hence triangles $BCO_{ABC}$ and $CBH_A$ are congruent and therefore $O_{ABC}Q_{BC}$ and $H_AP_{BC}$ are corresponding (congruent) altitudes, so $CQ_{BC} = BP_{BC}$. Thus, if $M_{BC}$ is the midpoint of edge $BC$ then $Q_{BC}M_{BC} = P_{BC}M_{BC}$.

Let $O$ be the center of the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Perform a $180^{\circ}$ rotation around point $O$ (i.e. the central symmetry with center $O$). Denote by $O^*_{ABC}$ the image of $O_{ABC}$ under this rotation. Observe $O_{ABC},\, O, \, O_{ABC}^*$ are collinear and $O_{ABC}O = O_{ABC}^*O.$ Furthermore, the image $h_{BC}$ of line $O_{ABC}Q_{BC}$ under the $180^{\circ}$ rotation around $O$ is parallel to $O_{ABC}Q_{BC}$ and $h_{BC}$ passes through $O^*_{ABC}$, i.e. $h_{BC} \parallel O_{ABC}Q_{BC}, \,\, O_{ABC}^* \,\in\,h_{BC}$, and since $O_{ABC}Q_{BC}$ is perpendicular to $BC$, line $h_{BC}$ is also perpendicular to $BC$.

Let $P_{BC}'$ be the intersection point of $h_{BC}$ and $BC$. Then the quad $P_{BC}'Q_{BC}O_{ABC}O_{ABC}^*$ is a trapezoid and the line $OM_{BC}$ is orthogonal to $BC$ (because $O$ is circumcenter of $ABC$ and $M_{BC}$ is the midpoint of $BC$), meaning it is parallel to both $Q_{BC}O_{ABC}$ and $P'_{BC}O^*_{ABC}$, and on top of that $OM_{BC}$ passes through the midpoint $O$ of edge $O_{ABC}O_{ABC}^*$ of the trapezoid. Therefore, $OM_{BC}$ is midsegment of the trapezoid $P_{BC}'Q_{BC}O_{ABC}O_{ABC}^*$, so its other vertex $M_{BC}$ is the midpoint of $Q_{BC}P_{BC}'$. It follows that $P_{BC}'M_{BC} = Q_{BC}M_{BC} = P_{BC}M_{BC}$ meaning that the two points $P_{BC}$ and $P_{BC}'$ coincide, i.e. $P_{BC} \equiv P_{BC}'$. Thus line $h_{BC} \equiv P_{BC}O_{ABC}^*$ is orthogonal to $BC$ and passes through $P_{BC}$. However, the altitude  $A_1H_{A}$ is by construction the line orthogonal to $BC$ and passing through $P_{BC}$. Therefore, line $h_{BC}$ is the line $A_1H_{A}$, i.e. $h_{BC} \equiv A_1H_{A}$ yielding the fact that line $A_1H_A$ is the image of $Q_{BC}O_{ABC}$ under the $180^{\circ}$ rotation around $O$.

Absolutely analogously, one can show that the other two lines $B_1H_B$ and $C_1H_C$ are the images of lines $Q_{CA}O_{ABC}$ and $Q_{AB}O_{ABC}$ respectively under the $180^{\circ}$ rotation around $O$. However, since the three lines $Q_{BC}O_{ABC}, \,\, Q_{CA}O_{ABC}$ and $Q_{AB}O_{ABC}$ intersect at a common point $O_{ABC}$, their three corresponding images  $A_1H_A, \,\, B_1H_B$ and $C_1H_C$ also intersect in a common point and that point is $O^*_{ABC}$.

Now we are ready to derive the proof for triangle $DEF$. Since triangles $A_1B_1C_1$ and $DEF$ have parallel corresponding pairs of edges, the two triangles are actually homothetic to each other. Then the three lines $A_1H_A, \, B_1H_B, \, C_1H_C$ which are orthogonal to the edges $BC, \, CA, AB$ respectively, are mapped by the homothety to the three lines through the vertices $D, \, E, \, F$ orthogonal to the edges $BC, \, CA, AB$ respectively. As we have already proved, $A_1H_A, \, B_1H_B, \, C_1H_C$  are concurrent, so their three images are also concurrent.

THE END

[image]

Comment: This is just what I wanted.

Comment: I would really like to know why my proof is "shaky"? It's quite understandable and short and just makes use of a relatively well-known Radical Axis Theorem. On the other side side I had troubles following your proof and I didn't read it till the end.

Comment: @Stefan4024 The facts are fine, I had the same proof before you posted the link and yes, the radical axis is standard, however your explanation is not as clear as you think. Personal opinion. I knew what was happening because I had the proof myself, but you have to explain how exactly you choose the circles and why the points $D, E, F$ lie on their radical axes. It's because of the power of point theorem (or whatever it's called). Plus I came up with some alternative proofs avoiding circles altogether. And my proof is long because I am a wordy person, I like to explain the details.

Comment: @Stefan4024 And I don't know why you would have troubles reading my proof, if everything is carefully explained. Lack of patience? But you don't need to waist your time if you don't want to.I just don't like proofs where when I read them, half of the facts I have to prove myself. Again, personal preference.

Comment: @SANTANUNANDI I added a picture.

Comment: First of all is not my proof. I just found it on the Internet and it seems fine to me and more or less everything is clear. On the other side for whatever reason in you proof I had to check everytime which point is where in the drawing and that's time-consuming and the proof is hard to parse.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Well, at first you said it was your proof. I just quoted you. If it's not your proof, you have no personal attachment to it. And don't read my proof. Don't like it. Downvote it. It's your opinion. Mine is that I did not like the ones in the link, they are not well written. I understood them, because I came up with more or less the same one with the radical axes myself. Your post appeared first, so I decided to come up with new ones. My proof is like this because I wrote it like that, because that's who I am. I like coming up with alternative proofs, and I write detailed proofs.

Comment: @Futurologist Well you called the proof I cited "shaky" without any reasonable arguement. I wonder whether you read the proof, as it says nicely: "By Radical Axis Theorem..." and it gives explanation how to choose the circles and why it is possible. On the other hand the lots of points in your circle makes it difficult to parse, at least for me.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Quote: "Choose $w_A, w_B, w_C$ such that $EF$ is the radical axis of $w_P, w_A$ and others similarly (note they exist because $AP \perp EF$ etc...)" It would be nice to clarify how you make sure you can do it consistently. Of course I know how and why it works, but it is not written! "By Radical axis theorem, $D$ lies on the radical axis of $w_B, w_C$". What theorem exactly? What does it say? It's the power of a point property combined with the definition of radical axis. Again, the proof is correct, but now written well in my personal opinion. And it my book, that's shaky.

Comment: @Futurologist The first one is true as the radical axis of two circles is always normal to the line connecting the circle's centers. The Radical Axis Theorem is well-known and there's no need of citing. It says that given 3 circles take the three pairs of circles. Then the radical axis of each pair of circles concur.

Comment: @Stefan4024 First quite: yeah but you have three axes and you have to make sure that all of them happen to become radical axes of the vertex circles with the one circle in common! Why does it work? One should give a reason why it works. And did you even read my second quite (objection)? It is not about the concurrence of the radical axes, it's about why the vertices $D, E, F$ happen to be on the radical axes.The radical axis theorem is used at the end, when all constructions are set! So this argument is not based on the radical axis theorem the way you say it does.

Comment: @Futurologist You fix the $\omega_p$ and you just select the other circles to satisfy the condition. Note that the line radical axis of $\omega_p, \omega_A$ isn't related to $\omega_p, \omega_A$. For the second case note that the we use the Radical Axis Theorem twice, once for the setting and once at the end, more precisely we use the radical axis theroem on of $(\omega_A, \omega_p, \omega_C), (\omega_A,\omega_p,\omega_B), (\omega_B, \omega_p, \omega_C)$ for the setting and then on $(\omega_A,\omega_B,\omega_C)$ to prove the final claim.

Comment: @Stefan4024, You see, that's my point, one needs to write some more detail to clarify. And by the way, I know very well the radical axis theorem, I have used it many many times.So I stand corrected, you can use the radical axis theorem twice, or you can use the power of a point property (which is actually in the first place how the radical axis theorem is justified). Still, the proof is sloppy and shaky.

Comment: @Futurologist There's no reason to expect one to fully explain proof into the smallest details, when more or less they are clear. Nonetheless it's your point and there's no reason continuing this nonsense.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

If the perpendiculars from $A$ to $EF$, $B$ to $FD$, $C$ to $DF$ concur, then the triangles are othologic and this is property is mutual, meaning that the perpendiculars from $D$ to $BC$, $E$ to $AC$, $F$ to $AE$ concur too. This is called the Maxwell's Theorem.

You can read more on this theorem and the orthologic triangles [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2335h1042068).